# Xcode 8 crash during submitting App Store

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, xcode8

I have a strange problem that never happened to me before. When I try submit my Xcode8 (Swift3) project to AppStore, after I choose and confirm organisation, Xcode crash with strange Issue report that says:

```
2016-09-17 12:32:29.604 xcodebuild[4347:14903] [MT] IDEDistribution: - [IDEDistributionLogging _createLoggingBundleAtPath:]: Created bundle at   path '/var/folders/90/5stft2v13fb_m_gv3c8x9nwc0000gn/T/Degoo-iOS_2016-09- 17_12-32-29.600.xcdistributionlogs'.
2016-09-17 12:32:31.335 xcodebuild[4347:14903] [MT] DVTAssertions:   ASSERTION FAILURE in  /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/IDEFrameworks/IDEFrameworks- 11246/IDEFoundation/Distribution/IDEDistributionSummaryStep.m:213
Details:  A method claimed to have succeeded but provided an error!
Object:   <IDEDistributionSummaryStep>
Method:   +_distributionItemsWithoutBitcodeForPlatforms:flattenedDistributionItems:ar chive:withError:
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7ff94ac07fe0>{number = 1, name = main}
Hints: None
Backtrace:
0   -[DVTAssertionHandler   handleFailureInMethod:object:fileName:lineNumber:assertionSignature:message Format:arguments:] (in DVTFoundation) 
1   _DVTAssertionHandler (in DVTFoundation)
2   _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundation)
3   +[IDEDistributionSummaryStep _distributionItemsWithoutBitcodeForPlatforms:flattenedDistributionItems:archive:withError:] (in IDEFoundation)
4   -[IDEDistributionSummaryStep distributionItemsWithoutBitcodeForPlatforms:withError:] (in IDEFoundation)
5   -[IDEDistributionSummaryStep loadFromPropertyList:error:] (in IDEFoundation)
6   -[IDEDistributionDriver runWithDestinationPath:error:] (in IDEFoundation)
7   -[Xcode3CommandLineBuildTool _distributeArchiveAndExit] (in Xcode3Core)
8   -[Xcode3CommandLineBuildTool run] (in Xcode3Core)
9  0x00000001047bb202 (in xcodebuild)
10   start (in libdyld.dylib)
```

I've also tried to upload app using bitrise, but I also failed but at least I know a little more. Below a `xcodebuild` backtrace just before a above crash log:

```
** ARCHIVE SUCCEEDED **


Generating exportOptionsPlist...
Using plist 3.1.0
Using bundler 1.13.1
Bundle complete! 1 Gemfile dependency, 2 gems now installed.
Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.

Configs:
  * export_options_path: /Users/vagrant/deploy/export_options.plist
  * archive_path:  /var/folders/90/5stft2v13fb_m_gv3c8x9nwc0000gn/T/bitrise- xcarchive.akKFUHmn/MyApp-iOS.xcarchive
  * export_method: app-store
  * upload_bitcode: yes
  * compile_bitcode: yes
  * team_id: 
  * plist_content:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN"  "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>method</key>
  <string>app-store</string>
  <key>uploadBitcode</key>
  <true/>
</dict>
</plist>

Exporting IPA from generated Archive...
$ xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath  "/var/folders/90/5stft2v13fb_m_gv3c8x9nwc0000gn/T/bitrise-  xcarchive.akKFUHmn/MyApp-iOS.xcarchive" -exportPath "/var/folders/90/5stft2v13fb_m_gv3c8x9nwc0000gn/T/bitrise-xcarchive.Jj61X7yX" -exportOptionsPlist "/Users/vagrant/deploy/export_options.plist"
```

Comment: Also having the same problem with a project i converted to swift 3 and xcode 8. Do you use carthage or other frameworks in your project too?

Comment: @Bjarte I use Cocoapods

Comment: I updated my answer with fix

Answer (score 1):

I spent hours on this issue without any clues.
I decided to start over from a blank project and backport all my files (except project files) + redo configuration.
It took me 2 hours, but the issue is now gone.

Comment: I did this too, and it worked for me. I'm not sure what the difference was, but the only things I noticed were  `LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS = (
     "$(inherited)",
    );` became `LD_RUNPATH_SEARCH_PATHS = "$(inherited) @executable_path/Frameworks";`, `objectVersion` went from 46 to 48, modules were enabled, and linking frameworks (on the project-general, where UIKit and CoreData used to go) was no longer necessary.

Answer (score 0):

This is a long shot, but are you using Reveal and the old-style method of copying the integration library into your app bundle? My build was doing that, but it was supposed to skip it if the configuration was 'ReleaseAppStore', which may have been an old name for archiving. I took that out and was able to validate and upload my archive.

Answer (score 0):

Ok found out what is going on. *(for short version skip to point 2.)*

1. I was able to go through the first part of validation *(part before selecting the team for binary and entitlement)* only with `bitcode enabled = NO` and have seen something weird. My app with entitlement was here but it was not alone. A class file with `.o` postfix was there, but it should not.
2. So I turned `bitcode enabled` to `YES` (not necessary to solve that), review the `Copy bundle resources` in `Build phases` and found that there really is the `.m` file of that class. So **I removed it**, check that the class is still part of the target (target membership) and everything is working now.

*Also Log in to your iTunes Connect account and check if **The updated Apple Developer Program License Agreement needs to be reviewed.** If yes, do so and try again.*

Answer (score 0):

Compile the project with the xcode 8 release and send the ipa to the store with the latest xcode beta. Or just try to clean the project and the build folder and try again.

Answer (score 0):

I had one 3rd party library which had `libswiftRemoteMirror.dylib`. Removed it manually from the archive and tried to export the IPA for test flight and it worked well.